# Using simple past without any time expression

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, tenses

I've heard that, simple past should be **always** associated with a past time expression (ex: yesterday, in 1958, etc...), in order to be considered as a complete sentence. Is that true ? Even though, a lot of native speakers uses the simple past without any time expression.

Examples:

> I bought a car using only pennies.
>
> I drove to New York and back for Star Wars!.
>
> I played in the band and sang in the choir.

Comment: What sources indicate this, and what do you mean by "a past time expression"? However, that aside, the sentence *I ran.* is grammatical.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you so much, I've updated my question

Comment: I'm interested to know where you heard or read this. It is simply not true that "_the simple past should be always associated with a past time expression in order to be considered as a complete sentence._". (The issue of what constitutes a complete sentence is irrelevant to the grammatical use  of a verb construction.)

Comment: @Shoe Thank you so much for the comment. I've heard that from a non-native English speaking youtuber, who teaches people English grammar online. He basically said that using past tense without a time expression, gives people the impression that your sentence is incomplete, so they expect you to tell them **when** the action/event has happened.

Comment: @Shoe I've posted this question in order to know if what he said is correct or not.

Comment: Ok, if I called you and said simply "_I bought a car_", then you might ask "_When?_" In such a context you may feel that my statement is incomplete. But in most conversations the starting context and the past time in which something occurred is implicit and clear or an exact past time reference is unimportant. For example, in a conversation about a trip to New York last week, you might say "_I bought a new phone in Macy's_." It's implicit that the buying happened last week, but the day and time are irrelevant.

Comment: So, it is certainly not true that "_an explicit past time expression is always needed when using the simple past_".

Comment: @Shoe Thanks a million for the awesome explanation and I would consider this comment as a great answer for my question (in case you post it as answer).

Comment: Please post the link to the youtube video where the host explained this "rule", and cite his or her words precisely. It's +1 from me if you do.

Comment: Thank you @Mari-LouA, I would definitely do that if he were explaining that in English.

Comment: Was the person, by any chance, explaining the difference between past simple and present perfect?

Comment: @Mari-LouA You hit the bullseye, he was talking about the difference between past simple and present perfect .

Comment: Right... so the person was probably saying that **whenever a specific time reference is mentioned** then the past simple should (always) be used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I just played the video again, but unfortunately I heard it right .

Comment: Well ... that's probably what they meant to say or *should* have said. EDIT The statement, if reported faithfully, is of course false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ignore the advice about complete sentences. The absence or presence of an adverbial such as a past time expression has no bearing at all on whether a sentence is considered syntactically complete.

There are occasions, however, when the listener might feel that a statement is incomplete in terms of the information it conveys. For example, if I call you and say: *I had an accident*, you would most probably want to know when (where, how, etc). Your statement may be contravening Grice's [Maxim of Quantity](http://www.linguisticsnetwork.com/semantics-gricean-maxims-1-2/), but certainly not flouting any rule of grammar.

Many statements about the past do not require an explicit past time reference - either because the time reference is clear and implicit or because an explicit time reference is unimportant.

For example, in a conversation about a trip to New York last week, you might say "*I bought a new phone in Macy's.*" It's implicit that the buying happened last week, but the day and time are irrelevant.

So, in summary, it is not true that "*a past time expression is **always** needed when using the simple past*". And I suspect that a very large majority of sentences with a past simple form do *not* contain such an expression.

Comment: and answering a question that includes a time expression doesn't require one to repeat or say a variant time expression: *Q: What did you do last week?* A: *I bought a new car*.